# Integration with infinity limits

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

We have to find the integration of

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x}{1+x^4} dx$$

In this I am not getting any start.

Comment: $\frac{x}{1+(x^2)^2}$. Try substituion $t=x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $x^2=t$, we have

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x}{1+x^4} dx=\frac 12\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{1+t^2} dt=\frac {\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Just substitute  $u=x^2$ to give us $$I =\frac {1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac {1}{1+u^2} du $$ giving us the answer as  $$\boxed {\frac {\pi}{4}} $$ Hope it helps.